# Conditionally settings tags with IF not working in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to conditionally create a tag for a resource, not just change the value. The tag should or should not be created based on a condition.

I looked at the docs and from what I found this should work:

```
  Tags:
    - Key: "sometag"
      Value: "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
    - Key: "someOtherTag"
      Value: "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
    # Only apply this tag if InDevEnvironment is true
    - !If
      - InDevEnvironment
      -
        - Key: "shouldNotEvenExistIfInProd"
          Value: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsf"
        - !Ref "AWS::NoValue
```

I get an error: `Value of property Tags must be a list of objects`

Cloudformation syntax has never been very intuitive to me, do I have the hyphen wrong or something?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was incorrect. The short form of if wasn't showing in the documentation I was reading. According to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if your syntax is incorrect for the short form of "!If". It looks like short form is done like this ```!If [CreateNewSecurityGroup, !Ref NewSecurityGroup, !Ref ExistingSecurityGroup]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that it does not work is due to indentation issues and non-needed double list use. I modified the code below:

```
Tags:
    - Key: "sometag"
      Value: "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
    - Key: "someOtherTag"
      Value: "sdfsdfsdfsdf"
    - !If
        - InDevEnvironment
        - Key: "shouldNotEvenExistIfInProd"
          Value: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsf"
        - !Ref "AWS::NoValue
```